# Gatling's jsonPath silently converts null object to "null" String

Tags: json, scala, jackson, gatling

I'm currently evaluating [gatling 3.3.1](https://gatling.io) for a use-case and need to retrieve JSON data from a server, manipulate it and send it back. Unfortunately, I've hit an interesting road block with null values in the response.

I'm using Jackson's ObjectMapper to deserialize and serialize the value to a `HashMap[Object,Any]`:

```scala
scenario("scenario")
  .exec(http("get")
    .get(url)
    .asJson
    .check(jsonPath("$").saveAs("json")))
  .exec(http("post")
    .post(url)
    .asJson
    .body(StringBody("${json}")))
```

Here's a website dummy to try it out: https://webhook.site/7130d3d3-ddcc-4c36-8864-c3a6c4c13cf4

The webserver returns:

```
{
  "name": "frodo",
  "note": null
}
```

The gatling script echos back:

```
{
  "name": "frodo",
  "note": "null"
}
```

You see, the note field became `"null"` instead of the correct `null`. Why is this happening? Is there a way around it? Am I doing something wrong? Some Jackson option I'm missing?

Comment: Try `"${json.jsonStringify()}"`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung unfortunately, that does not change anything. The generated string contains still `"null"` and not `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [bug](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3928) that will be fixed in the next release (3.4.0).
Thanks for reporting but next time, could you please use our bugtracker on Github? :)

Comment: Thanks. I would have used the bugtracker if I had known that it was a bug. I didn't expect it to be and thought that maybe it was a limitation of Scala or some weird edge case.

Comment: Cool, then. Thanks again for the great reporting, it made it very easy to investigate and fix.